# Schema.org type for online encyclopedia entries - article or dataset?

Tags: schema.org

I am looking for recommendations on what schema.org type to use for entries in an online encyclopedia.

My initial thoughts were to define entries as 'article', but I am now leaning towards 'dataset' as I don't feel these are articles in a news sense.

Looking for any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

[**`Article`**](http://schema.org/Article) should be appropriate. It’s not only for news (for which there is the more specific [`NewsArticle`](http://schema.org/NewsArticle) type), but also for scientific papers, microblog/blog posts, guides/tutorials, forum posts, etc.

[**`Dataset`**](http://schema.org/Dataset) is for "structured information". The typical encyclopedia entry probably isn’t *structured* in that sense (e.g., I wouldn’t use it for Wikipedia, but maybe for DBpedia).

If you think both types could be appropriate for your case, you could use them together (i.e., each entry is an `Article` *and* a `Dataset`).